# ganache-cli issue

Tags: truffle, testrpc, ethereumjs

Until I switched to ganache-cli from testrpc things were working fine. Now I ran testrpc and 10 accounts are displayed as shown below.[image: Starting testrpc]
But I am unable to deploy any contract. it is stuck after this-[image]
I tried re-installing testrpc but the issue persists. Please help!

Comment: Can you show us your truffle-config.js? Is development port configured to point to 8545?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Parity running in the background you might want to kill the process.

If that does not work/apply, try running miner.start() in your web3 console. This will start the miner and your contract will be deployed on the network.

More on this issue [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/305)

Comment: Yes! You were right. Parity had been running in the background.Thanks